# LINQ how to get data using Id’s

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Ok I have all the carers that have clients from their local authority, but how do I get the client’s name? The client’s name is stored in the client table linked by ClientId. I would like to do it all in one query if possible.

Any pointers much appreciated.

```
var Records = (from x in db.Cares                         
              where x.LocalAuthorityId == ClientLocalAuthorityId    
                 select new {
                    ClientId = x.ClientId,
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: You're working with entities, classes, properties and collections, not tables and JOINs. The `Carer` class should have a `Client` or `Clients` property. Whatever ORM you use (is it Entity Framework?) will fill the related properties itself. It's the ORM's job to generate the JOINs

Comment: Post classes which are used in the query. It will help to examine which navigation properties exists in your model.

Comment: What is `db`? What ORM are you using?

Comment: Thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv INNER JOIN worked, but I need to get the client names via the ClientId. Yes I'm using the Entity Framework and Microsoft SQL

Comment: The Client table and Carer table are lined by ClientId i.e. a client can have many carers. I just need to the client name from the client table, but not sure how to do it all in one query.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what the first two comments tried to tell you. Apart from that, it's hard to help you  based on this bit of information.

Comment: @JoeBlack what is `db`? What ORM are you using? Without that information the question will have to be closed as unclear. You shouldn't be using any JOINs. You aren't working with tables. You shouldn't have to write anything more than `from carer in db.Carers where .... from client in carer.Clients select new {...}`

Comment: I have 2 tables Clients table and Carer table. 
The tables are linked by ClientID.
The ClientID is the primary key in the Client table and is the foreign key in the Carer table. The Carer table holds the carer’s address and the ClientID’s. 
I’m looking to create one query to get all the Carer’s information and client’s names who reside in the same local authority.
Each table has address column which has their local authority.

Comment: Please find internet results on how to use navigation properties in EF (which I assume you use but you still didn't clarify). This is very basic stuff. Also, please [edit] your question to add new info, not comments.

Comment: @GertArnold do you mean 'Edit Summary'? I can't see an option for 'New Info'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I've worked it out

```
     var Records = (from c in db.Cares  
                   join x in db.Clients
                   on c.ClientId equals x. ClientId into eGROUP                                      
                   from x in eGROUP.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   where x.LocalAuthorityId == ClientLocalAuthorityId                    
        select new {
                      ClientName = x.ClientName,
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Still no navigation property. Ah well, it's your code.